# Prove that $ \sum_{k=1}^T t_k f(x_k) \leq B \Rightarrow \min_{ k \in \{1, \ldots, T \} } f(x_k) \leq \frac{ B }{ \sum_{k=1}^T t_k } $

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Suppose $f(\cdot)$ is a positive real function, with positive real coefficients $t_k$s, and we know:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^T t_k f(x_k) \leq B
$$
Can we prove that?
$$
\min_{ k \in \{1, \ldots, T \} } f(x_k) \leq \frac{ B }{ \sum_{k=1}^T t_k  } 
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ are non-negative numbers with sum $S$, then
$$ \min_{k\in[1,n]} a_k\leq \frac{S}{n}, $$
since if we assume the opposite:
$$ S=a_1+\ldots+a_n \color{red}{>} \frac{S}{n}+\ldots+\frac{S}{n} = S$$
we get a contradiction.

Comment: But here your have a coefficient $t_k$, which might be different from other $t_{k^\prime}$ for $k^\prime \neq k $.

Comment: @Daniel: the proof is just the same. If you assume $\min f(x_k)\color{red}{>}\frac{B}{\sum t_k}$, you get a contradiction, since $$\sum t_k f(x_k)\geq \left(\min f(x_k)\right)\cdot \sum t_k.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The negation of $\min\{a_1, \ldots, a_n\} \le K$ is $\forall i = 1, \ldots, n: a_i > K$. Use this to prove your claim via contradiction.